# breezejs: Nonscalar navigation properties are readonly (Many-to-many issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm using AngularJS for data-binding and everything works fine except when I use a control of type multi-select. Instead of adding or removing an element to the model, it actually replaces it with a new array. Breeze then raises the following exception:

`Nonscalar navigation properties are readonly - entities can be added or removed but the collection may not be changed.`

The problem with Angular is that most controls, if not all, use the $setViewValue(value) function, which takes the new value as parameter, in this case an array.

Is breeze not being a bit too restricting here ? Does someone have a workaround for this scenario ?

My code is:

```
<select ng-multiple="true" multiple  class="multiselect" data-placeholder="Select Contacts"  ng-model="request.contacts" ng-options=" ng-options="c as c.username for c in contacts track by c.id" />
```

where contacts is a navigation property of the entity bound to the parent controller and myContacts is the collection of contacts on the $scope.

**EDIT**

I've changed my code to use ng-change and an intermediary collection :

```
<select ng-multiple="true" multiple  class="multiselect" data-placeholder="Select Contacts" ng-change="updateBreezeContacts()"  ng-model="model.selectedContacts" ng-options="c as c.username for c in contacts | filter:{clientId: requestService.selectedRequest.client.id} track by c.id"></select>



$scope.updateBreezeContacts = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.selectedContacts.length; i++) {
               $scope.requestService.selectedRequest.contacts.push($scope.model.selectedContacts[i]);
 }
}
```

When I push the entity to the array, I still get the error message  reported above.

How come ??

**EDIT 2**

I figured it out. The problem is that now breeze tries to assign the Request entity to the newly added Contact. But the Contact entity has a list of Requests, not just a single Request. This is a many-to-many relationship, that is not supported by breeze (at least with Entity Framework).
To make it work, I've exposed the association table as an entity. When the user selects a Contact in the multiselect, I then create a RequestContact entity which is then pushed into the list of RequestContact entities on the Request entity. It's far from being neat code so :

**My next question is that I'm using NHibernate so is there a way to make it work or would it be supported soon  ?**

Answer (score 1):

You are listing the options properly but you are trying to write a value to a navigation property directly - you can't do that, never have been able to, and by design shouldn't be able to.  You want to create a navigation property from the child to the parent, not shove children into a parent's property with no key between them.

Why not set up an array to put your selected objects into, and then <strike>$watch</strike> use **ngChange** on the array and set

```
contact.request = thisRequest;
```

whenever it is added and

```
contact.request = null;
```

when it is removed?

Comment: sorry but the code I've posted was actually wrong. See the new code in my post. That works for dropdowns bound to a collection of breeze entities. However, in the case of the multi-select, it breaks with the error I've mentionned.

Comment: If you go this route: **Don't use a $watch, use ngChange** it fires less frequently, and it leverages the $watch already set up by the <select> directive and ngModel.

Comment: I use ngChange as per your recommendation, but I still get the error message - see my edit

Comment: Sorry bud but so.com is here to help with small programming related questions.  You keep chaining new questions on to your old one, and the newest is more of an architecture question.  You need to start a new question or read up on breeze.js docs

Comment: sorry, I've drifted away with that one. I also had to put it on hold for a while. I've created a new post today with better explanations and more details on what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: It would be good to either close this question or mark it as an accepted answer if it was helpful to answer your original question for future visitors to know which path to take.